# How do I install LibreOffice 4.0.2?

Tags: installation, libreoffice, dpkg

After I upgraded to 13.04 I noticed that Libreoffice 4.0.2 wasn't working, at all. When I click its launcher I get the this start up box:

[image]

which amounts to no program being opened.

I have downloaded the tarball from this [webpage](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/?type=deb-x86&lang=en-GB&version=4.0.2) and extracted it and ran `sudo apt-get purge libreoffice4.0` to clear all prior installations and then I `cd` to the directory of the extracted tarball, then I ran `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` and then went `cd` to the desktop-integration subdirectory and then ran `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` and received the output:

```
dpkg: regarding libreoffice4.0-debian-menus_4.0.2-2_all.deb containing libreoffice-
debian-menus:
 libreoffice-core conflicts with libreoffice-unbundled
  libreoffice-debian-menus provides libreoffice-unbundled and is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing libreoffice4.0-debian-menus_4.0.2-2_all.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing libreoffice-debian-menus
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libreoffice4.0-debian-menus_4.0.2-2_all.deb
```

Comment: I have to ask, did you download the right package?

Comment: yep I'm running 32 bit (x86) 13.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to remove any previous installations of Libreoffice.(if any)

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

There are 2 ways to install:

1.

Add the right repository:

**Warning**: if you have another LibreOffice PPA installed, you might have to remove it first

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-0
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

2.

Download the right Libreoffice package for you, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the folder where the file was downloaded extract the archive. run the command below:

```
tar -xzvf libreoffice*.tar.gz
```

Then do

```
cd libreoffice*/DEBS
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Once done, then

```
cd desktop-integration
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

That's it.

Comment: First line gave me the output: `[sudo] password for brentonhorne: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libreoffice4.0-debian-menus_4.0.2-2_all.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libreoffice4.0-debian-menus_4.0.2-2_all.deb'`

Comment: Which first line?

Comment: sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*

Comment: That means its not installed.  Just choose your installation option.

Comment: What installation option?

Comment: What I've listed in my answer.  I recommend that you choose the first one.

Comment: I did the first option and it failed; I clicked the libreoffice writer launcher and it failed (did what is in that screenshot in my question)

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-core`

Comment: Done, what now?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem try `sudo apt-get -f remove --purge libreoffice*` and then reinstall!

Answer (score 0):

**Understanding your situation by summarizing the posts and stating any key assumptions, and providing my preferred "Approach"-Stick with Supported Version of LO from Ubuntu Software Centre**

The response has three parts- Disclaimer of limitations; Defining the problem, defining an approach and lastly a note on Ubuntu software centre with respect to LO packages.

I hope that the length of my response is justified by its completeness.

---

*My Limitation:* I posses not technical qualification in Computer or Software. While using Ubuntu, my approach is to gather just enough knowledge to enable me to use Ubuntu in all ways that I can use Windows. **Therefore** I focus on approaches to problem rather than the technical aspects involved in its implementation. Fortunately there are many users who provide help on technical aspects. Accordingly I am attempting to suggest an approach and also offer some justifications.

I use Ubuntu 12.10 along with default LO 3.6. version as updated by Ubuntu. I will stick with 12.10 till LTS 14.04 around April/May 2014..A conservative approach which will also reflect in the solution below.

---

From your post and its replies, I understand that LO installed with 13.04 did not work. Your solutions was to install it from LO website. This process was not successful. To fix this, the solutions given in the posts involve:

1. Cleaning up the earlier LO related files (using *purge*)
2. Then attempt re-installation using either the dep package downloaded from LO website OR use of PPA.

My solution involves **cleaning up** the OS of LO related files (**including Binaries**) and then *use Ubuntu Software centre* to **Re-Download LO** and install it.

Further I am assuming that the OS upgrade process is not contributing to this problem. Although auto upgrading option is available, I did come across suggestions to avoid this and instead do a clean install--i.e. delete earlier version and install the new version a fresh.

Also note that if you have upgraded from earlier version of Ubuntu, then you may need to *purge* the previous version of LO (version 3). I am assuming that there was no such need or that you purged the earlier LO version (or the *purge libreoffice4.0* command that you have used, also cleans earlier LO version).
(As this effect involve technical understanding about usage of purge option, Kindly confirm it from your end. I believe that the usage of "libreoffice*" in answer 2 ,should remove any and all versions of LO)

**Some background material to enable understanding **

*Three sources for LO*:

1. Ubuntu software centre (officially supported version for a given distribution version). More stable..
2. LO website with the appropriate program (say deb file)..advantages are we get latest version and from a trusted source.
3. PPA (Ubuntu does not support this,One gets updated versions and often tweaked for Ubuntu)

Right now the version from Ubuntu is current enough.So going for latest update is not an adequate incentive (at least for me).**Therefore I prefer** the Software Centre Approach.

*How to prevent Ubuntu from using potentially corrupted LO binaries while we re-install LO using Software centre*

Ubuntu stores the binaries of LO so that any re-installation can be done using it, thus avoiding re-downloads from Ubuntu servers.(the stored Binary can be from the installation DVD or from Ubuntu server)

*Assuming* that the original LO binaries were corrupt (hence LO installed is not working), We need to un-install LO *as well as* remove the stored Binaries. Using *purge* option, does this two tasks.
So after purge, the OS has no LO installed and no Binaries of LO.

---

Now that the system has no traces of LO or its binary, we can download it afresh from the Ubuntu Software Centre.(this is simple enough so I an not elaborating the steps)

**Note** on packages Selection from Software Centre:

- Out of the LO packages "Base" (database) needs Java. By default "Base" and "Java" are not installed. To avoid Base (and Java) it seems that we have to download individual packages separately say Libreoffice Writer/Calc/impress etc.
- There is a package named "libreoffice" which will install all packages including base and related programs.

**End of my Reply**

Answer (score 0):

My Ub Software Center LibreOffice install to 13.04 runs and works seemingly well, but even after repeated cleans and reinstalls the Ub Software Center app throws an error for the disorganized state of the LO browser add-in, where these errors appear Each time Ub Software System is used to install Any software.  And several apps that work well for me on a 12.04 partition will Not install at all on 13.04, where fifty others install and run like on 12.04.  Presently a mystery.